# Underdamped bipolar square wave with Arduino

Tags: circuit-design, wave, square

I want to ask about a 30 Hz (decaying square wave) underdamped bipolar square wave.Also this is used for demagnetization. The photo of the output is shown as below. Could you help me to construct? Any recommendations?

[image]

Comment: Is this an assignment? We help with those BUT not the same as for non assignment questions. || A decaying square wave would be unuseual. Damping usually implies a load removing energy from an oscillatory circuit and you'd usually expect a sinewave or similar. The shown waveform could come from eg an underdamped sine wave and a zero crossing detector and peak detector. THe relationship between input and output may be more complicated than expected.

Comment: THe term "underdamped square wave" is used in blood pressure monitoring but does not mean what you show here.

Comment: Once more :-) - you REALLY need to tell us the context and how that waveform was produced.

Comment: Why is the 2nd negative peak at -10 volts and not -9 volts? What's going on here?

Comment: If this circuit is underdamped sinusoid, how can I convert this circuit sinusoid to square wave?

Comment: @too6hort with a simple comparator vs 0V, but the result would have constant amplitude, but changing frequency. As the others say, it's very questionable what you actually *need*, so if you'd explain more of the context of your question, its purpose and the origin, you'll potentially get answers that help you much better!

Answer (score 1):

You could make this using a DAC with bipolar output, so you could make a [breakout board using this IC.](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad5724r.html?doc=ad5724r_5734R_5754R.pdf#product-overview)

Then you can program an Arduino to communicate with the DAC to tell it to output 12, then -12, then 10, then -10 and so on. That is the only solution I can immediately think of for making very square waves.